# How to get Messages by the consumer according to priority of the messages set by the publishers RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmq-shovel

I have publish messages with some priority set for a single consumer(i.e single consumer that may receive messages according to message priority).
What i want is to get that messages and print them according to the message priority on the consumer side. Hey guys Help me out in this !

```
public class Send extends Thread {

   int priority; 
   String name = "";
   String app_type = "";
   private static final String EXCHANGE_NAME = "topic_exchange";

    public void run()
    {
        ConnectionFactory connFac = new ConnectionFactory();
        connFac.setHost("localhost");

        try {

                Connection conn = connFac.newConnection();
                Channel channel = conn.createChannel();
                channel.exchangeDeclare(EXCHANGE_NAME, 
                BuiltinExchangeType.TOPIC);
                for(int j=1; j<=200; j++)
                {
                    randomWait();

                    int random = (int)(Math.random() * 10 + 1);

                    String routingKey = j+"."+"update"+"."+app_type;
                    String msg = name;
                    channel.basicPublish(EXCHANGE_NAME, routingKey, new 
                    AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder()
                            .contentType("text/plain")
                            .deliveryMode(2)
                            .priority(priority)
                            .build(),
                            msg.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                    System.out.println("Sent " + routingKey + " : " + msg + 
                    " "+" Priority : "+priority);
                }

                channel.close();
                conn.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Send.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, 
             ex);
            System.out.println("Exception1 :--"+ex);

        } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Send.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, 
          ex);
            System.out.println("Exception 2:--"+ex);
        }
    }

     void randomWait()
    {
        try {
           Thread.currentThread().sleep((long)(200*Math.random()));
        } catch (InterruptedException x) {
           System.out.println("Interrupted!");
        }
    }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        Send test1 = new Send();
        test1.name = "Hello ANDROID";
        test1.app_type = "ANDROID";
        test1.priority = 10;

        Send test2 = new Send();
        test2.name = "Hello ANDROID";
        test2.app_type = "ANDROID";
        test2.priority = 5;

        test1.start();
        test2.start();
    }
}
```

In the above code I have use thread to pass the priority and message value and started the both the thread at the same time to publish messages with different priorities. I have set the priority value in the AMQ Builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The queue has to be [configured to support priority](https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html).

Comment: Can consumer retrieve messages from the queue according to message priority. That is suppose consumer respective queue have messages(M1(5), M2(1), M3(3)........), now can consumer retrieve M1(5) first as it has higher priority.

Comment: Yes, of course, as long as the queue is properly configured - read the documentation link in my answer.